# jQuery Border Animation

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to animate a button click by using borders and jQuery animate function.

```
jQuery( '#sendForm' ).hover( function (){
    jQuery( this ).animate({
        borderTopWidth: "5px",
        borderBottomWidth: "0px"
    }, 'fast' );
}, function (){
    jQuery( this ).animate({
        borderTopWidth: "0px",
        borderBottomWidth: "5px"
    }, 'fast' );
});
```

From some reason it doesn't animate the top border only the bottom.

**Update**

```
.submitButton { 
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 0px; 
    border-bottom: 5px solid #1B5A81; 
    background-color: #267DAD; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Comment: it should work, have you set a default border value in CSS?

Comment: could you show your style for `#sendForm`? or even better, check and update this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maALV/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the problem, i had to define border type and color in the CSS:

Fixed CSS:

```
.submitButton
        {
            padding: 10px;
            border: 0px;
            border-top: 0px solid white;
            border-bottom: 5px solid #1B5A81;
            background-color: #267DAD;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can also accomplish the same thing using CSS3 transition [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kPF4E/1/)

HTML

```
<button>BlahBlah</button>
```

CSS

```
    button {
   border-top: 5px solid #ff0000;
   border-bottom: 0px solid #ff0000;
   transition: border-top 2s, border-bottom 2s;
   -moz-transition: border-top 2s, border-bottom 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
   -webkit-transition: border-top 2s, border-bottom 2s;; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transition: border-top 2s, border-bottom 2s; /* Opera */
}

button:hover {
   border-top: 0px solid #ff0000;
   border-bottom: 5px solid #ff0000;
   transition: border-top 2s, border-bottom 2s;
   -moz-transition: border-top 2s, border-bottom 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
   -webkit-transition: border-top 2s, border-bottom 2s;; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transition: border-top 2s, border-bottom 2s; /* Opera */
}
```

CSS3 transitions [w3 link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)

Comment: thanks, it doesn't support IE so i will stick for now in jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you want it?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZPPj/)

I changed the css to

```
.submitButton { 
    padding: 10px; 
    border-bottom: 5px solid #1B5A81; 
    border-top: 0px solid #1B5A81; 
    background-color: #267DAD; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}​
```